# Adding three different char in java as java variable and getting a number

Tags: java, intellij-idea

[IntelliJ IDEA Capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1IbY2.png)

Why i am getting 152, I think it will give me an error.
Please explain it.

```
    public class character {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        char myCharValue1 = 'A';
        char myCharValue2 = '2';
        char myCharValue3 = '%';

        System.out.println(myCharValue1 + myCharValue2 + myCharValue3);
    }
}
```

Comment: try making it a String first. `"" + char1 + char2 + char3`

Comment: `char` is actually a 16-bit (2 bytes) data-type. Using `+` will cause them to behave like numbers. Use `new String(...);` or `new StringBuilder().append(myCharValue1).append(myCharValue2).append(myCharValue3).toString()`.

Comment: I got A2% after adding string.

Comment: Really helpful thank you big bro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because `char`s refer to a number, which in turn has an ASCII representation.

Looking at an [ASCII table](https://www.asciitable.com/) you can see that the chars `A`, `2` and `%` have following values respectivly: `65`, `50` and `37`.

Adding those numbers together, you'll end up with `152` which is what you got in your example.

---

To print out those `char`s you could use following:

```
System.out.printf("%s%s%s&n", myCharValue1 + myCharValue2 + myCharValue3);
```

Which will print `A2%` (and a newline)

Comment: Thank you big bro.
I think that's the correct answer.
Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

The concatenation `+` is for `String`. What you're doing is adding the numeric values of your `chars` and printing them together.

If you start with `""` and then use `+` as Patrick Parker shows in his comment, it will become concatenation instead of simple addition and you'll get the result you expect.

Comment: Hmm, just try to use it in different way.
and Now i get that what is the actual problem.
Thank you Kayaman.